CRYSTALS-Dilithium barrett reduction variation
I have a burning question about Dilithium that I've been trying to figure out for a while. On the source code that's available on the github (here) there is a reduce32 function - why is this used?
I know this is some variation of Barrett reduction but I can't quite understand A) how does the output range get within [-3Q/4, 3Q/4] and B) why the input is 2^31 - 2^22 - 1.
I also don't fully understand how this function is related to Barrett, I just read that in here (Section 3.2). The addition of (1<<22) confuses me - I'm thinking it's to get a within 2^31 - 1 but again I don't get how the input even gets subtracted by 2^22.

If the role of addition $1<<22$ in Dilithium be same as the role of addition $1<<25$ in Kyber Github, reduce.c t  = ((int32_t)v*a + (1<<25)) >> 26; ,it is for creating ${mod}^{\pm}$, i.e., for causing the result in the range $[-\frac{3Q}{4},\frac{3Q}{4}]$. By looking at the code Gitgub - Dilithium t = (a + (1 << 22)) >> 23; it makes more sence, since $\frac{2^{22}}{2^{23}}$ create $\frac{1}{2}$. I hope my guess helps.

The relation between $mod$ and ${mod}^{\pm}$: If $x\mod m > \frac{m}{2}$ then $x$ must wrap around by adding $\frac{m}{2}$ to it for generating a result in ${mod}^{\pm}$ form.
